Getting HiZ for my output for a 5 to 1 mux
I'm having trouble with Verilog code for a 5 to 1 MUX.
module Mux_5_to_1( m, s0, s1, s2, u, v, w, x, y );

    input s0, s1, s2;
    input u, v, w, x, y;
    output m;
    wire m0, m1, m2;    

    Mux_2_to_1 Unit0 (m0, s0, u, v); 
    Mux_2_to_1 Unit1 (m1, s0, w, x);
    Mux_2_to_1 Unit2 (m2, s1, m0, m1);
    Mux_2_to_1 Unit3 (m, s2, m2, y);
     
endmodule

module Mux_5_to_1_tb;

    logic S0, S1, S2;
    logic U_in, V_in, W_in, X_in, Y_in;

    wire M_out;

    MUX5TO1 DUT (S0, S1, S2, U_in, V_in, W_in, X_in, Y_in, M_out);    
 
    initial begin 
        for (int i = 0; i<=8; i++) begin
            {S0, S1, S2, U_in, V_in, W_in, X_in, Y_in} = $random; #10;                    
        end
    end

    initial begin
        $monitor( S0,,, S1,,, S2,,, U_in,,, V_in,,, W_in,,, X_in,,, Y_in,,, M_out );
    end

endmodule


Your code is not in a state where it would even run. Your test bench instantiates MUX5TO1, but your module is called Mux_5_to_1. What is Mux_2_to_1? Hi-Z means something is not connected, so in whatever code you are actually using, make sure that everything is connected.

There are 2 mistakes in the code that you posted:

You used the wrong module name in the testbench: MUX5TO1.

You have the port order wrong for the DUT instance.  You should connect the M_out wire to the DUT output port, which is the first port in the list.  The simulator I used gave me a compile error; perhaps Modelsim was more forgiving.


To fix these 2 errors, change:
MUX5TO1 DUT (S0, S1, S2, U_in, V_in, W_in, X_in, Y_in, M_out);

to:
Mux_5_to_1 DUT (M_out, S0, S1, S2, U_in, V_in, W_in, X_in, Y_in);

You are using connection-by-position.  It is better to use connection-by-name to avoid these common Verilog errors.  Refer to Verilog: How to instantiate a module
